# If Statement half working

Tags: php, if-statement

I am making a page for submitted info. When the person does not fill out a box (in this case being the first name) it is supposed to change $okay to FALSE. Now this code only half works, when I run it 
it prints out the sentence but does not change $okay to false.

```
<?php
   $FirstName = $_POST['firstname'];
   $LastName = $_POST['lastname'];
   $Email = $_POST['email'];
   $CompanyName = $_POST['companyname'];
   $Description = $_POST['description'];
   $okay = TRUE;


   if (empty($FirstName)) {
       echo '<p class="error"> Please enter first name</p>';
       $okay = FALSE;
   }


   if ($okay = TRUE) {
       echo "<p> Thank you $FirstName $LastName. We are looking foward to doing business with you. Please look for an email at $Email from
               BrandingYouSmall@gmail.com for '$CompanyName' </p>";
       echo "<p> Your Description: <br /> $Description </p>";
   }
?>
```

Comment: Why not just make that an else?

Comment: I am going to add several more, one for each box. It's only one now because it was my first attempt at this and I wanted to make sure it worked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if($okay = TRUE){
```

That's a problem. Single `=` is operator of assignment. So you tell "Set $okay to TRUE". But you want to CHECK. So you need to use equality operator - `==`. Fix it:

```
if ($okay == true) {
```

or shorter:

```
if ($okay) {
```